# can one define multiple job queues for the same compute environment in a cloudformation stack for AWS batch?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

I would like define multiple job queues for the same compute environment in a cloudformation stack for AWS Batch.

I have one job queue called "*InterpreterTrainingJobQueue" and another called

"*ModelPromotionJobQueue"

as defined below, but only the last job queue "*ModelPromotionJobQueues" shows up in the AWS Batch console.  Does this mean that an AWS Batch cluster can only have 1 job queue?

The goal is to be able to send different jobs to different queues using the same AWS Batch cluster.

```
  JobQueue:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobQueue
    Properties:
      ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
        # Use on-demand instances
        - Order: 1
          ComputeEnvironment: !Ref ComputeEnvironment
      State: ENABLED
      Priority: 1
      JobQueueName: !Join ['-', [!Ref ProjectName, 'InterpreterTrainingJobQueue', !Ref DeployName]]


  JobQueue:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobQueue
    Properties:
      ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
        # Use on-demand instances
        - Order: 1
          ComputeEnvironment: !Ref ComputeEnvironment
      State: ENABLED
      Priority: 1
      JobQueueName: !Join ['-', [!Ref ProjectName, 'ModelPromotionJobQueue', !Ref DeployName]]
```

Update with new resource id's for each job queue:

```
  InterpreterTrainingJobQueue:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobQueue
    Properties:
      ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
        # Use on-demand instances
        - Order: 1
          ComputeEnvironment: !Ref ComputeEnvironment
      State: ENABLED
      Priority: 1
      JobQueueName: !Join ['-', [!Ref ProjectName, 'InterpreterTrainingJobQueue', !Ref DeployName]]

  ModelPromotionJobQueue:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobQueue
    Properties:
      ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
        # Use on-demand instances
        - Order: 1
          ComputeEnvironment: !Ref ComputeEnvironment
      State: ENABLED
      Priority: 1
      JobQueueName: !Join ['-', [!Ref ProjectName, 'ModelPromotionJobQueue', !Ref DeployName]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the same ResourceId for both: `JobQueue`, CloudFormation overwrites the first resource. Try using a different name, preferably based on what their purpose is. E.g `InterpreterTrainingJobQueue` and `ModelPromotionJobQueue`.

Comment: Thank you.  I created unique ResourceId's for each queue, but on stack update, cloudformation says it failed to created to create the new resources.  Any ideas on how I can get cloudformation to recognize the new resources ids?

Comment: @morfys It failed why? Any errors? Also can you update the question with new version of your template you are trying to execute now?

Comment: Yea, please post the error. My first suspicion is a name conflict, CloudFormation creates new resources (new resource ids) before deleting old ones (old resource ids). If that's the case, tear down the stack first or use different names.

Comment: Thank you.  Deleting the stack helped.